# Cycle through a Picker selection from Array

Tags: swiftui

I'm quite new to Swift and coding in general so apologies if this is a super simple question.

I'm trying to add a button either side of a Picker to allow the user to move up/down the selections within the Picker (my Picker is populated from an Array) - I'm using this selection in another part of my App.

The code below works but only updates the example Text, but it does not update the selection: within the pickerto update correctly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let myArray = ["Period 1", "Period 2", "Period 3", "Period 4", "Period 5", "Period 6", "Period 7", "Period 8", "Period 9", "Period 10", "Period 11", "Period 12", "Period 13"]
    @State var currentIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    if currentIndex == 0 {
                    } else {
                        currentIndex -= 1
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                }
                .padding(2)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                Picker(selection: $currentIndex, label: Text("Picker")) {
                    ForEach(myArray, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    if currentIndex == 12 {
                    } else {
                        currentIndex += 1
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                }
                .padding(2)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                
            }
            .padding()
            
            Text("\(myArray[currentIndex])")

        }
    }
    
}
```

'''

Comment: Unrelated but maybe a Stepper would be a better choice than a Picker here.

Comment: Thanks, I have considered that (and have an example in code) but the UI didn't quite work for my use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that you are programmatically updating your State variable `currentIndex` but you are not modifying the array selection. To make this work you need to iterate the array over the indices and not the elements so change the `Picker` code to this

```
Picker(selection: $currentIndex, label: Text("Picker")) {
    ForEach(myArray.indices) { index in
        Text(myArray[index])
    }
}
```

Here each item in the picker automatically gets the `id` of the raw value of `index` which matches with `currentIndex` which makes this work.

To work directly with the elements of the array here is an alternative solution where a new State variable is added to hold the selected string.

```
@State var currentSelection = ""
@State var currentIndex = 0 {
    didSet {
        currentSelection = myArray[currentIndex]
    }
}
```

The picker code gets changed to

```
Picker(selection: $currentSelection, label: Text("Picker")) {
    ForEach(myArray, id: \.self) { period in
        Text(period)
    }
}
```

but the rest of the code is the same since the buttons are still using `currentIndex`

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much for explaining where I was going wrong :) thank you!

Comment: Searched all over for for loading picker from array and setting it up properly.  Great answer!